# Change hover color of Glyphicon on button when button is hover on CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to change the `glyphicon-chevron-up` color when the button it is on is hovered on

The button:

`.btn.btn-success.text-uppercase.m-b-xs.sort-button`

The Glyphicon (this works if I hover on the Chevron):

`.glyphicon-chevron-up:hover:before`

I am trying

```
.btn.btn-success.text-uppercase.m-b-xs.sort-button:hover .glyphicon-chevron-up:hover:before {
   color: orange !important;
}
```

but only works if I hover on the Chevron directly

Thanks in advance for assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It's working perfectly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <style>
        .btn:hover .glyphicon{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Chevron-left Glyph</h2>
      <p>Chevron-left icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></p>    
      <p>Chevron-left icon as a link:
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p>Chevron-left icon on a button:
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Left
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>Chevron-left icon on a styled link button:
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Left
        </a>
      </p> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run it using the Run code snippet button below. Let me know it's working or not.

Comment: I see, in sort by button you didn't put any glypicon name. you need to use  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> this way. Here glyphicon-chevron-left is the icon name. after adding this when I hover on the button. Another thing is may me you need to update the bootstrap cdn.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. I will see if I can get the developer to do these things

Comment: May be it's  CSS specificity issue. that's why it's not working in your code. You can check it in a clean slate.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue this way.

```css
.btn:hover .glyphicon{
        color: red;
}
```

When you hover over the button the content colour inside the glypicon class will become red. You can use your desired colour.

Comment: Thanks for the response! but that is not working even with !important added

Comment: I tried it and it's working perfectly. I am giving you the whole code. inside another. answer.